# Parameter is not valid exception when saving image in winform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting a parameter is not valid exception..While saving the image

Here is my code to save the image

```
if (!File.Exists(pictureBox1.Tag.ToString()))
{
    Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
    image.Save(pictureBox1.Tag.ToString(), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
else
{
    string delStr = pictureBox1.Tag.ToString();
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    File.Delete(delStr);
    Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
    image.Save(delStr, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(delStr);
}
```

Comment: Please give more details about the exception (full message etc) *and* which branch of the "if/else" statement it was from.

Comment: I am getting the error at image.save()...I want to save the image with the same name

Answer (score 3):

In your `else` branch, you start by calling [Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z.aspx) on your `Image`, then you try to save it. That can't possibly work, because:

> The `Dispose` method leaves the `Image` in
>   an unusable state.

Maybe you wanted to do:

```
string delStr = pictureBox1.Tag.ToString();
File.Delete(delStr);
Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
image.Save(delStr, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
image.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(delStr);
```

But that's still reloading the `Image` from the very file it has just been saved to, so it's not very useful. You might want to try something like:

```
string filename = pictureBox1.Tag.ToString();
if (File.Exists(filename) {
    File.Delete(filename);
}
pictureBox1.Image.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But then again, [Image.Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) will overwrite the file anyway... So you only need to do:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(pictureBox1.Tag.ToString(), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Test.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: @hasan, maybe you have the image file open in some editor while you're running your program?

Answer (score 1):

Am I seeing correctly? Are you disposing the image before saving it? If so here is your problem:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); // THIS !!!!!! Just remove this line or move it to after save
Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
image.Save(delStr, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: If i dont dispose it...it gives me error that i can not delete it because it is used by some process...All I want to do is to save the image with the same name i.e. without save file dialog

Comment: @Hasan can you perhaps give of insight on the reason?  You still have not told us which parameter is giving you the error.

Comment: image.Save(delStr, ImageFormat.Jpeg) I am getting the error here